# How does one give critical advice without killing morale?

Tags: feedback-methods

I've been tasked with tutoring some people, and after some sessions, I gave quite negative feedback to someone, and killed their morale. I tried to say the negative feed back in a "nice way".

1. I avoided any fighting words, and tried to make it not about they as a person.
2. Suggested that I believe that improvement is possible, but they need to work on certain areas a lot more.

Yet, after I gave my remarks, they felt quite negative about themself.

What are some tips I could keep in mind to have a person retain their morale to do something when giving negative feedback for next time?

Comment: How long ago did you give this feedback, and how long did their drop in morale last?

Comment: Well happend today, and I'm not sure @Tinkeringbell

Comment: Just what kind of feedback did you give?  By that I mean, was it of the form "this page is not coherent" or did you give them specific items to fix, like "in this paragraph you refer to 'he' but it isn't clear who 'he' is"?

Comment: I gave general statements, and specific statements. A person I'm tutoring @DaveG. For instance, I did say that the work was bad, and I also tried to explained why the work was bad specifically in details, and I also gave them a track to improve/ fix their problem

Answer (score 6):

You have two issues here: the person you gave that feedback to, and future people. I train and tutor people a lot, and people often seek out my feedback, so I have experience telling people they are "doing it wrong".

For the person you gave the feedback to, you should seek them out and check in with them. "I want to make sure my feedback didn't come across more negatively than I intended. I don't want to discourage you from [this career, learning this thing, working here.] My intent was -- " and this right here is the hard part. What was your intent? You need like 4 words here. Maybe 5. Must they always remember to X before they Y? Is safety more important than speed? Do they have to ask every time? Is it wrong to stop before the numbers balance? You need to know what the absolute core of your feedback was **before** you try to fix being overly harsh.

This isn't an email or some other one-way message. You find them (ideally in person, but online chat if you must), you let them know you're aware you may have been crueler than you should, and you deliver that core defect report that they simply must receive. You let them respond or ask questions or whatnot until they understand both the core defect report and your overall well-wishing to them. Then you reiterate your belief they should continue in this industry or whatever and some confidence that they can overcome whatever it was you had to correct in them. You smile nicely and encourage them to reach out to you any time they want support. And then you drop it. You can't poke them every month or two "hey remember that time I crushed your morale? You still ok? You over it yet?"

Now, for future people, understand that feedback is not always requested. People have paid me good money to listen to them try public speaking and then say how it was. That doesn't mean I can randomly approach someone giving a talk and tell them their flaws. At a bare minimum, even in a training context, you get consent. "Can I give you some presentation tips?" "Can I suggest why you may have found that exercise so difficult?" "Do you want some career advice?" Sure, in a training context the person is going to automatically say yes, but they will be prepared for the kind of thing you are now going to say. It won't be so shocking. And when you develop the habit of asking for consent like this, you'll catch yourself when you're about to offer criticism inappropriately, such as in front of their peers, when they think they're doing super well, or when they're already upset about something else (like not getting an exercise done.)

Finally, when you're wording things, there is such a difference between telling someone how they are doing, and telling someone what they should change. "You make a lot of trivial arithmetic mistakes" hurts. If you stop there you have upset the person for nothing. Go the extra mile and say "take the time to double check before moving on" or "look for a way to check your work, say back-substituting, to catch those things." It is not the same at all to say "you talk too fast" as to say "you should try talking more slowly" and it's even better to give people some tips about how to talk more slowly.

The worst feedback is "you are bad at this." It's not much better to say "you are doing this badly." To be helpful you need to be specific and you need to include suggestions about how to fix whatever the problem is. Not "work on" something. You have to be precise. Should they practice a particular skill? Until what point? What will happen when they do? Does everyone struggle with that at first? Did you? All this is much more reassuring than "improvement is possible, but". If you don't have time to tell them how to get better (in a training context!) then why are you taking the time to tell them they're not doing it well?

Comment: _I want to make sure my feedback didn't come across more negatively than I intended._ are you sure this is a good advice? You actually admit that the feedback was intended to be negative. How can anyone not take this the wrong way?

Comment: The OP intended the advice to be taken as "you need to improve your X" not "you shouldn't be in this field". It was intended to be negative, but that's not a 0 or 1 thing, some feedback is more negative than others.